# Firebase authentication not working using variables but works for hardcoded values

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a registration page using HTML, js and firebase.
I have a form which takes email and password to store for registration in firebase database.Below is the HTML form code. I have included the the scripts for initializing firebase config at the top(have not added them here)

```
<form>

          <div class="field-wrap">
              Email Address
            <input type="email" id="email"/>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
              Set A Password
            <input type="password" id="password"/>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button button-block" onclick="registerUser()">Get Started</button>

 </form>
```

Below is the code snippet for the js page.I dont see any error in the console, but neither do I see any entry in firebase authentication db. (The alert in the code prints the correct email and password as passed from HTML)

```
    function registerUser(){
        var email =document.getElementById("email").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

            alert("email is:"+email+" password is:"+ password);

firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).catch(function(error) {
              // Handle Errors here.
              var errorCode = error.code;
              var errorMessage = error.message;
              console.log(errorMessage);
              // ...
            });
    }
```

But the below code works(hardcoding email and passoword), and I can see the mentioned email and password in firebase authentication db. Not sure why using variables for email and password are creating a problem in above js code

```
function registerUser(){
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword("myemail@email.com","mypassword").catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(errorMessage);
          // ...
        });
}
```

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: Is your page redirecting on submission? if so, it may not be giving the asynchronous `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` time to complete.

Comment: @bojeil its just the javascript function and HTML code which I have pasted in the question , there is no redirection from javascript .. only redirection is from the HTML page submit button to the javascript.

Comment: When you click submit, that is submitting your form and redirecting. This is interrupting the createUserWithEmailAndPassword.

Comment: @bojeil. So what would be the correct approach .. also if this is the case then even while hard coding it shouldn't work right  because Even when hard coding I am redirecting from HTML page

Comment: Try adding this to your button: `onclick="registerUser();return false;"`